# split string into array of hashes with data on delimeter

Tags: html, ruby, string

I have a string like the following:

```
lorep ipsum <a href="#" class="link-1">dolor sit</a>amet, consectetur <a href="#" class="link-2">adipiscing</a> elit.
```

I need to split it into fragments, but save link classes for fragments inside anchors. So perfect result would be:

```
['lorep ipsum ', {'link-1' => 'dolor sit'}, 'amet, consectetur', {'link-2' => 'adipiscing'}, ' elit.']<br />
```

Or:

```
['lorep ipsum ', ['link-1', 'dolor sit'], 'amet, consectetur', ['link-2', 'adipiscing'], ' elit.']
```

I've tried using this code:

```
string.split(/<[^>]>/)
```

But it returns returns only an array of fragments.

Comment: Why don't you try using an HTML parser like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do using [`Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/)

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-eot
lorep ipsum <a href="#" class="link-1">dolor sit</a>amet, consectetur <a href="#" class="link-2">adipiscing</a> elit.
eot

ary = doc.search("//a").flat_map do |n,a|
   [n.previous_sibling.text.strip,{n['class'] => n.text.strip},n.next_sibling.text.strip]
end.uniq

p ary
```

**output**

```
["lorep ipsum", {"link-1"=>"dolor sit"}, "amet, consectetur", {"link-2"=>"adipis
cing"}, "elit."]
```

Comment: isnt it overkill to use nokogiri to parse string?

Comment: @kabukiman *NO* it is not. It is recommended to use Nokogiri for parsing HTML/XML.